# How can i change the range of the y Axis - dc.js composite Linechart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Some Informations:
I have a composite Linechart.
And my Question is:
Im using elasticY but my axis beginns at 0 but my smallest value can be 250.
Is there a chance to start the Y Axis from 250 and not from 0 ? But the dynamic Y axis should work (elasticY)

```
    var compositeAvg = dc.compositeChart("#avgline-chart");

    compositeAvg.width(1500).height(375)
        .group(filtered_group)
        .brushOn(true)
        .yAxisLabel("Morbalwait AVG ")
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal()) //x axis
         .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .margins({ top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 })
        .elasticY(true)
        .elasticX(true)
        ._rangeBandPadding(1)
        .compose(composeLines())
        .legend(dc.legend().x(1425).y(0).itemHeight(13).gap(1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([250, yourmaxvalue]))

Comment: The Problem is my Max Value is always diffrent :/ I'm getting my data from a database

Comment: I think you can get automatically the max value something using top function, check out this: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top